# How to bind a method to class during its metaclass's __init__ method?

Tags: python

**Final Edit**

My problem was that I was trying to bind a partial to a class. Not sure if I should delete this question or, change its title.

**Original Question**

I know that [the "correct" way](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-39/example-adding-methods-to) to bind methods to a class inside its metaclass is to add it to the `classdict` argument in the metaclass's `__new__` method, and that in general you can bind an instance method to a class by simply assigning it to the class.

However, in my use case, I need to bind a method to a class during the metaclass's `__init__` method. The problem is that the usual method of assignment does not work. The function is assigned to the class and it can be access via `ClassName.function_name` or `class_instance.function_name`, but it is not bound to the class, and the first argument is not set to `self`.

I guess that this is due to the class not being fully initialized during the metaclass `__init__`, but is there any way around this problem?

**EDIT: Code Example**

Given:

```
def fun(self):
    pass


class MetaClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        pass

class Class(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
```

I want to bind `fun` to `Class` inside `MetaClass.__init__`, so that calling

```
instance = Class()
instance.fun()
```

will pass `instance` to `fun` as its first argument.

**Edit The II**

So, apparently the problem arose because I was trying to bind a partial. Not sure why that would cause an issue.

Will make sure later, and update/remove this question if necessary.

Comment: A partial is not a regular function; most importantly it is not a descriptor.

Comment: I see. Guess I'll have to look into descriptors. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is little difference between `metaclass.__new__()` and `metaclass.__init__()`; they both deal with the class object.

`__new__` produces the new object, `__init__` then gets to alter it still. The chain of events is basically:

```
new_class_obj = YourMeta.__new__(YourMeta, name, bases, bodydict)
YourMeta.__init__(new_class_obj, name, bases, bodydict)
```

When it comes to adding functions on the new class object (through the `bodydict` or directly by assignment on the class object) there is no difference at all.

If you are having problems setting functions on the class object, then you need to make sure you are setting actual function objects on that object.

If you are using *bound methods* for example, you need to unwrap the method and extract just the function:

```
new_class_obj.name = method_obj.__func__
```

If you are adding *regular function objects* on the class, then they'll be bound when accessed on the instance, no work required on your part.

Bottom line is that you need to add *something* that'll act a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), specifically a descriptor that'll return a method object from the `descriptor.__get__` method. This is what plain function objects do.

A `functools.partial()` object is **not** such a descriptor. Easiest would be to wrap the partial in a function (a `lambda` will do here):

```
new_class_obj.name = lambda *args, **kw: partial_obj(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: No, I am setting an instance method on the class. `__metaclass__.__init__` runs on class declaration. There is no instance at that point.

Comment: @RomanLevin: so the method is coming from an instance? Then it is already a bound method, but bound to another instance. Can you post the code?

Comment: @RomanLevin: That's not enough of a sample. *What is `func` when you add it to `cls`?*

Comment: It is an unbound function. I don't see how this is not enough. Where have I not been clear?

Comment: @RomanLevin: Then it should *just work*. You put an unbound function on the class, it will be bound when accessed on an instance of that class.

Comment: @RomanLevin: If it doesn't work for you, then something else is wrong, and I'll need to see more code.

Comment: So you're saying that doing `new_class_obj.bound_func = func` inside `__init__` will bind `func` to `new_class_obj`?

Comment: It'll bind to the *instances* of `class_obj`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant. It does seem to work. Strange. I'll find where it differs from my working code and post an update later.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the metaclass `__new__` has already called the `type.__new__`, which is the thing that turns the functions in the class dictionary to unbound methods as part of constructing the class object.

You can construct methods using the `types` module. Your code would look something like this:

```
import types

def fun(self):
    pass

class MetaClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls.fun = types.MethodType(fun, None, cls)

class Class(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass
```

NB: this is for python2, I don't know if this has changed in python3.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. A class dictionary contains plain function objects. It is *accessing* these functions as attributes on the class or the instance that triggers the [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) (through the `__getattribute__` method on `object`).

Comment: In other words, `Class.fun` is executed as `Class.__dict__['fun'].__get__(None, Class)`. `Class().fun` is executed as `Class.__dict__['fun'].__get__(Class(), Class)`. The class dictionary **does not store method objects**.

Comment: The `type.__new__` method *certainly* does *not* store `types.MethodType` objects on the newly created class.